# Automatically submit From Values with php

Tags: php, forms

I have the below `form` under `if` in php. Now what I'd like to accomplish is somehow, submit those values without automatically if the `if` condition is true.

Without having to display another page to the user and have them click the button.

```
echo ('<form method="post" action="URL" class="animate">

<input type="hidden" name="mode_login">
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="URL">
<input type="hidden" name="accept_terms" value="yes">

<button type="submit" value="Enter">Grain Access</button>

</form>');
```

Is this possible?

I'm a newb just starting with php...so be kind. Thanks.

Comment: a form cannot be submit by php.You can use javascript

Comment: @ShaifulIslam I know I can use JS. However, I am looking for a solution to write out the hidden values manually as variables in php. And then have then sent to another page. Is something like that possible?

Comment: Yes possible. Produce javascript code with php code

Comment: I am really looking for a solution that doesnt involve JS. Can php send variables to another page on it's own without JS?

Comment: your from is client side and php is server side. You cannot do it.

Comment: but if you know the values you can do it using curl,session,get.Actually its hard to understand what you really want.

Comment: I know the values. I just need to pass them along to a URL that will process  them. I am just not sure how to write the hidden input as a variable that will be read exactly as if it were coming from a form? @ShaifulIslam

Answer (score 0):

To get it to submit automatically, just add some JavaScript into the echo which will submit the form once the page has loaded.

With PHP being a server side language, you can't get PHP to do the submission, but you can get it to output something to the client to cause the submission.

Edit: Following the discussion in the comments on getting the values passed through to a different page/script, try something like the following with sessions:

```
$_SESSION['redirect'] = 'URL';
$_SESSION['accept_terms'] = 'yes';

echo ('<form method="post" action="URL" class="animate">

<input type="hidden" name="mode_login">
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="' . $_SESSION['redirect'] . '">
<input type="hidden" name="accept_terms" value="' . $_SESSION['accept_terms'] . '">

<button type="submit" value="Enter">Grain Access</button>

</form>');
```

Comment: I really meant the values of the form. Can't they be turned into variables (manually) and then transferred across to another page? Without having to involve javascript.

Comment: You could use sessions to pass store the values and then pull them back later.  Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Comment: I am familiar with seasons. However I don't really know how to turn the hidden values in the form into variables. And how to send them to another page with php?

Comment: I've updated my answer to give you an idea.  If I was trying to do what I think you're looking to do, I'd do it that way.

Comment: Thats not really what I'm asking. There is really no need for the form. I already know the values. I am just unsure how to write them as hidden inputs in php and how to pass them along using php under IF. The processing script should see them as if they were submitted through a form.

Comment: If you already know the values, how do you now them?  Have they already been submitted?  If so, they will already exists as a $_GET or $_POST variable (and as a $_REQUEST one too).  From the script you are on, can you include the file they need to be used in and just access the $_XYZ variables?

Comment: These are the values `$_POST['mode_login'] = 'mode_login';`
`$_POST['redirect'] = 'redirect-url';`
`$_POST['accept_terms'] = 'yes';`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69989/discussion-between-gabe3886-and-boris).